# MD5 hash working in SQL Server 2016 but not in 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which runs fine in SSMS 2016, but the same query in SQL Server 2008 throws an error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

When looking at the query, I saw that there is a column which is `text` that is creating the issue. The `Notes` column is of datatype `text`. How do I fix this to run this without any error in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT 
    [id],hashbytes('MD5', (SELECT [id], [version], [status], [notes],[locked], [timelocked] 
                           FROM (VALUES(NULL)) foo(bar) 
                           FOR xml auto)) AS [Checksum]
FROM 
    tableA AS A
```

Comment: Try CASTing `Notes` as `varchar(max)`?

Comment: tried that but still got the same error

Comment: Or just change the column to avoid being forced to cast. Also, might consider a different hash than MD5 as that has been proven weak for quite a long time now.

Comment: How long is the value being passed in? That is most likely where the issue lies. In 2014 or earlier the input max length is 8,000 bytes, also the max output is 8,000 bytes.

Comment: some of the notes are 10000 bytes

Comment: Well there you go. It is too long for hashbytes. See the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017